# Apple Developer Program Enrollment ID

Tags: iphone-developer-program

I don't know if it is correct to ask this question here, but I'm sure that many of you know the answer. Currently I'm in the process of applying for Apple iOS Developer Program. I filled in the Purchase Form, but I could find the **Apple Developer Program Enrollment ID**. I found just Individual ID, Person ID(that I used in the Purchase Form) and Company ID(don't know what it means, because I'm registered as Individual Developer).

**Question:** Where can I find Apple Developer Program Enrollment ID?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need the Apple Developer Program Enrollment ID?

I also tried to apply to the iOS Developer Program this weekend.
I applied, I paid and I got my activation codes. But then when I tried to activate with my Apple ID I got an error saying (in my case) they "were not able to successfully verify my identity". In that error message there was an Enrollment ID# consisting of both letters and numbers, a total of 10 characters, that I was supposed to include when contacting the support regarding this issue.

I have not seen the same Enrollment ID somewhere else in the process and therefore I assume it is some kind of internal ID for my signing up process and you should only see it/use it when you hit some problems during the process.

Answer (score 2):

It's the iTunes Store Account (Apple ID) that you will use to login in the Developer portal. If you already have one use that, if no, then create one http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2731

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem -- in a call to their customer support they said it was because my Apple ID was under my nickname, "Jim", but the developer info I entered was "James".  They said a human eventually reviews these blocks, but that can take time.  Just be sure to try and use the exact same info.